# SwiftUI NavigationLink Error: Unnamed argument #2 must precede argument 'destination'

Tags: swiftui

[image: code]

[image: error message]

[image: market view code]

How do I fix this? The recommended fix just causes more problems. I have code in another project where this exact same scenario works but when I'm applying it to this project I get an error I've never seen before. Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Please paste your code as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out it had something to do with the function buttonhit. Once I fixed it, it works now

Answer (score 0):

Write the Image and both Text in VStack in the Navigation Link.